# Organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, organic-reduction, organic-oxidation

Could someone tell me what happens when a compound having a benzene ring reacts with a mixture of NaOH/HCHO?
What reaction and mechanism does this follow?

Comment: Could you please choose a more specific title? Also exactly what compound is this? What other functional groups does it have, or is it just benzene (doesn't seem to be based on your description)? A bit more detail will go a long way in getting a better answer...

Comment: Sounds to me as if you need some other reactants or substituents, and it would help if you gave us more detail on the reaction conditions.

Comment: @orthocresol yes ok sorry, I'll attach an image of the compound

Comment: As your question stands, there is no reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example of a reaction like this is the reaction of Benzaldehyde and Formaldehyde in the presence of a basic hydroxide (OH<sup>-</sup>).

This reaction proceeds as follows:

[image: Reaction 1]

Thus, using Sodium Hydroxide (NaOH), The reaction would yield Phenylmethanol (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>5</sub>CH<sub>2</sub>OH) and Sodium Formate (HCOONa, sodium salt of formic acid)

If you want a better answer, or if this was not quite what you were looking for, you can try to better define your "Benzene Compound"

Comment: Thanks a ton! This helps!! My compound was phenol with a OMe (Methoxy) group in the ortho position

Comment: @user762391 "My compound was phenol with a OMe (Methoxy) group in the ortho position" – Then why don't you tell us in the question? And this compound has a name, so use it!